# Unable to install Internet Explorer on MAC OS X 10.7.4

Tags: macos, mac, internet-explorer, microsoft

I have a mac mini containing **MAC OS X 10.7.4**

**I must need to go through some sites / links which are strictly allowed only for InternetExplorer,**

So that i **installed** ie on my mac,

***while open*** ie application it doesn't opened and prompt amessage like as follow,

***`You can't open the application Internet Explorer because PowerPC applications are no longer supported.`***

what should i do.. i need internet explorer very usrgently

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963475/unable-to-install-internet-explorer-on-mac-os-x-10-7-4?noredirect=1#comment26256483_17963475

Comment: The last Mac version of IE is version 5, and it is PowerPC only. The last OS capable of running it was 10.6 (PPC emulation via Rosetta).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Internet Explorer for Mountain Lion.

If you must have IE you need to run Windows virtually (e.g., with Bootcamp).

I would try the Chrome or Firefox (or Safari) on Mac and see if they can work for you.

In Safari, you can try this:

1. Go to Safari > Preferences > Advanced > click on Show Develop Menu in Menu Bar.
2. In Develop menu > User Agent > Internet Explorer 9.0

This might trick the websites into thinking that Safari is Internet Explorer.

Comment: I'll also add: Internet Explorer used to be available in an old version for Macs, but it only ran under Power PC. Macs starting with Lion (I believe) stopped shipping with Power PC compatibility, meaning that once you have a Mac with Lion or higher installed you cannot run PPC apps like IE.

Comment: In addition, Microsoft stopped any further work on IE for OSX in 2003, so any technology developed for web serving/browsing in the past decade probably wouldn't work. Buscar's workaround is your best option if you don't want to run actual or virtual Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Download Wine And Install The Windows Version Of IE

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.